# C/C++ SOCKET Proxy

Tags: c++, c, sockets, proxy

Currently, I implemented a client and server application which use simple SOCKETs to communicate with each other. Like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The problem is that some users don't have a direct access to the internet, so they use proxys.

How can I use SOCKETs for a communication over a proxy (e.g. default IE proxy), or is there any other possibility?

Comment: Documentation said that *If you are running through separate proxies for each service, you shouldn't need to do anything. If you are working through sockd, you will need to "socksify" your application*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, there are different types of proxies and different types of protocols used by those proxies.  There are HTTP proxies, SOCKS proxies, Tunneling proxies, etc.  So first you need to decide what type(s) of proxies you want to support in your code, and then implement each of those protocols as needed.

In general, instead of `connect()`'ing directly to the desired server, the client would `connect()` to a proxy server instead and instruct it to connect to the server, using whatever protocol that proxy uses.  Once that connection has been established, the rest of the client and server code would `send()` and `recv()` data normally as it already is, and the proxy would transparently exchange the data back and forth.